# Azure Service Bus Shared Access Signature

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

We're looking to limit the power our projects have over manipulating our Azure Service Bus.

Currently all projects have visibility of all topics and queues, is there a way for a single service bus to have multiple shared access keys which give visibility to certain topics and queues?

For example:

- Service Bus A

  - Topic A

    - Queue AA
    - Queue AB
  - Topic B

    - Queue BA
    - Queue BB

Service Bus A should have two shared access policies

- Policy A gives access to Topic A, Queue AA and Queue AB
- Policy B gives access to Topic B, Queue BA and Queue BB

In this scenario we could give Policy A to Project A and Policy B to Project B.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Do you want to have a single client to use multiple keys or multiple clients with a dedicated key?

Comment: Elaborated original question, cheers. But to answer your question it could be both. We want to control what the project sees in the same way you would control a DB users access to tables and procedures.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Documentation you can have up to 12 rules per SB namespace, queue or topic.  The rules can either give Send, Listen or Manage permissions.

The documentation & samples for what I think you are trying to achieve is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas

This includes a table at the end which lists the permissions required for each operation

HTH

Comment: ^Correct. More succinctly put: Each queue or topic can have it's own set of Shared Access Keys (Permissions) - you can give out these keys to the services that need them, reducing their access footprint.